# GeoFencing while the screen is locked

Tags: android, geofencing

I followed the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing) and set up GeoFencing in my app.
In my `MainActivity`

- I get permissions
- I create some geoFences
- I add geoFences via `geofencingClient.addGeofences`, with `onSuccess` tgriggered
- I listen for `Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT` and `Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER` in a `BroadcastReceiver`

I do receive the Transition notifications, when the phone is awake and the app is running.
But when the screen is locked or app is killed - nothing happens.

**Question:**

What do I have to do, to get the transition notifications, which the phone is locked? 
Do I have to wake the phone?

Comment: I did something like this using a foreground service that listens for location updates.  You cannot get geofencing alerts unless your app is getting location updates. if you open google maps while your app is locked or killed and google maps gets a location update your app should fire a transition. You have to use a foreground service

Comment: Sry I have not understood. My **app** should get location updates? This is a requirement for GeoFencing? Is that documented somewhere?
What should I use the foreground service for and why not a broacastReceiver (to react on GeoFencing transitions)  ?

Comment: read this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits